# How to link folders to sections of my Github page

Tags: github, hyperlink, configuration, jekyll, github-pages

On my github page I have a tab at the top called projects, and I have a bunch of my projects listed there.

I created a second tab at the top called initiatives, but I wasn't able to fill in my initiatives the same way.

So my projects.md calls on my _posts folder (where I have projects listed), and I'm trying to make my initiatives.md call on my _postsi folder (where I have filler initiatives in there)

https://github.com/tusharjoshi1/tusharjoshi1.github.io
www.tusharjoshi1.com

Comment: I am reading https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/ article. From the looks of it all contents must be contained in a folder called _posts. Is it possible to have a secondary blog on the same website?

Comment: Okay so the issue is that _postsi is not defined in _config.yml anyone know how I can do this?